# JAX-RS: JSON deserialization to legacy objects - how to provide helpers/factories to legacy interfaces?

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jsonb, apache-tomee

I have a situation while building a stub test server for testing our newly written client for a legacy system, where I would like to deserialize an incoming JSON request body to an object hierarchy provided by a vendor for the same legacy system.

In other words I would like to use the vendors classes instead of building my own.

I've managed to make the Eclipse Microplatform client (running in latest TomEE) come as far as starting to populate the base legacy object but then it fails with not being able to instantiate an interface inside the object which makes sense as there is no metadata for this.

```
  @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public String post(MessageObject messageObject) {
```

```
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>javax.json.bind.JsonbException: interface /vendor interface class/ not instantiable
    org.apache.johnzon.jsonb.JohnzonJsonb.fromJson(JohnzonJsonb.java:200)
    org.apache.johnzon.jaxrs.jsonb.jaxrs.JsonbJaxrsProvider.readFrom(JsonbJaxrsProvider.java:182)
...
```

As I do not have the source for these classes, I was thinking of whether the deserializer could be told otherwise (like Providers in Dependency Injection) how to instantiate the interfaces.  I have full control over the client.

I am not very familiar with this, so I would appreciate knowing how to get around this or is this a failed cause?

Comment: Is using Jackson not an option? Jackson has Mixins, which are very useful for situations like this.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can bind an implementation for interfaces, see https://johnzon.apache.org/, johnzon.interfaceImplementationMapping part. It can be set in resources.xml in the configurable provider. The class to set is https://github.com/apache/johnzon/blob/master/johnzon-jsonb/src/main/java/org/apache/johnzon/jaxrs/jsonb/jaxrs/JsonbJaxrsProvider.java and the property key is interfaceImplementationMapping, its value is using properties syntax.

Hope it helps